# Javascript embed for external sheet?

Tags: javascript, jquery, embed, selector

I have this code for a poll(javascript):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://i0.poll.fm/survey.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  polldaddy.add( {
    type: 'slider',
    embed: 'poll',
    delay: 100,
    visit: 'single',
    id: 7523190
  } );
</script>
```

I want to put:

```
{
    type: 'slider',
    embed: 'poll',
    delay: 100,
    visit: 'single',
    id: 7523190
  } );
```

that part in a external .jss file. What is the best way to do this? And is it even possible? Is there something like a ID selector for javascript? Like # is for CSS?

Thanks x

note:

I tried this but it still does not work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("polldaddy.add")
{
    type: 'slider',
    embed: 'poll',
    delay: 100,
    visit: 'single',
    id: 7523190
  } );

</script>
```

---

UPDATE on kevinB message:

I've tried what you said, still doesn't work check out my code:

```
HTML:
<!DOCTYPE html>


<html>

    <head>

    <title>De auteur</title>
<link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="myscript.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

myscript.jss:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://i0.poll.fm/survey.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  polldaddy.add( {
    type: 'slider',
    embed: 'poll',
    delay: 100,
    visit: 'single',
    id: 7523190
  } );
</script>
<noscript><a href="http://polldaddy.com/poll/7523190/">Ga jij bewust om met social media?</a></noscript>

</script>
```

Dont know what I'm doing wrong but it still does not work!

Comment: Does if have to be an anonymous object? And if so why? If it does not, simply create a variable for the object (say `var content = { /* ... */}`), else I would write a function that returns the object say `function content()` and use `polldady.add(content())`.

Comment: why you can't download the external js and edit it and include in your code?

Comment: Why not put that entire script section as a whole in an external js file? wouldn't make much sense to have an external js file that just defines a global var that gets immediately used by an inline js script on the following line.

Comment: @kevinB How do I do this? How do I connect the external to my html? Can I use a selector?

Comment: you wouldn't need a selector, you would jsut put all of your code inside of a .js file and include it the same way you did the other one. `<script type="text/javascript" src="myjsfile.js" charset="utf-8"></script>`

Comment: @kevinB Can you check out my post again? I tried what you said (i put it in my new edit) but it still does not work what am I doing wrong?

Comment: myscript.js can only contain javascript, but you'rs contains html. that's invalid.

Comment: @kevinB So its impossible to put the whole poll in Javascript? only the var?

Comment: well, no, it isn't impossible, it's just impractical. You very well could include another javascript file with javascript and then execute code on the methods it defines.

Comment: Basically, you can use the second snippet from jacob's answer, moving the contents of <script> into pollData.js rather than having it after the script include.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about just defining it as a variable in the external JavaScript file and then using that variable to add the poll? Something like:

pollData.js:

```
var pollData = {
    type: 'slider',
    embed: 'poll',
    delay: 100,
    visit: 'single',
    id: 7523190
  };
```

HTML:

```
<script src="http://i0.poll.fm/survey.js"></script>
<script src="pollData.js"></script>
<script>
  polldaddy.add(pollData);
</script>
```